# Developing iPad / iPhone application in same project or in 2 separate (Monotouch)?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios

We know that in monotouch we have 2 solution for developing a project for both iPhone and iPads.

First is using Montouch iPad Application projects for iPad, and Monotouch iPhone Application projects for iPhone and create two separate project for each of them.

Another solution is using one Universal Projects for both o them.

The question is: what solution is better and with witch one the result has more quality?

Comment: you mean iPad/iPhone, don't you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pros and cons of `Universal app`.

Pros:

- One place to fix bugs in app's business logic;
- Convenient to users (after install on one device it could be automatically installed on other device);
- Marketing costs could be half as much;

Cons:

- It could be too many `if` -blocks, which are checks for `UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom`;
- Bigger app size;
- Some of the features (mostly in games) do not fit well on iPhone's display.
- If you used XIB-based interfaces, you must make separated XIB for iPad **OR** update XIB content layout in UIViewController's `ViewWillAppear` event (in which iOS updates View frame according to display size);
- If your app is not free, you couldn't release "HD version" with bigger price.

Basically, universal app is better for users, but harder for developers and designers.

Comment: In Xamarin 4 I am unable to create 2 separate xib files for ~iPad and ~iPhone How can i create ? @Maxim Korobov

Answer (score 3):

I think, you are asking about iPhone and iPad. Because, universal app includes iPhone and iPad (not iPhone and iPod).

So considering this:

You should go with Universal app because of below reason:

1) There will be one source file of the app which will work in both iPhone and iPad.

2) If user has both devices (iPhone and iPad), then they get a single copy of the app and can install in both devices.

3) Your app supports both devices, so users will be highly attract and download your app quickly.

4) If your app will more downloaded (because of Universal app) then there are chances that, your app comes into "New and WhatWorthy" section and even "Feature" section of the apple.

There can be main reason why we should go for Universal app instead of separate app for iPhone and iPad.

Hope, you got an idea.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks to your reply it was useful.